# can i set the default value of my function parameter as value from another function

Tags: python, django, function

in my django project i have a function to  get the latest report object from the django modal. my function is as shown below

```
def get_latest_id():
    if something:
       return id
    else:
       return None
def get_report_obj(id=None):
    if not id:
        id = get_latest_id()
    if not id:
        return False
    try:
        report_obj = report.objects.get(id=report_id)
    except report.DoesNotExist:

        return False
    return report_obj
```

can i set the default  value of my function parameter as value from another function as shown below

```
    def get_report_obj(id=get_latest_id()):
        if not id:
            return False
        try:
            report_obj = report.objects.get(id=report_id)
        except report.DoesNotExist:

            return False
        return report_obj
```

This code works for me.  Is it a proper way of coding? anyone help me please.

Comment: I haven't been active with python in a while so idk if you can declare a function parameter with a default value of a function. But your new way should be fine, having one if statement in a function isnt a problem.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for the command sir

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
def get_report_obj(id):
    try:
        report_obj = report.objects.get(id)
        return report_obj
    except report.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

and when you call the function *get_report_obj* you provide the parameter as the *get_latest_id* function like:

```
try:
    get_report_obj(get_latest_id())
except ....:
    ....
```

By directly providing id as a function when calling *get_report_obj* inside a try except, you guarantee that the parameter id exists which makes the if statements redundant.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I need to avoid the unwanted db call if report id is not there.

Comment: You should always have an id, the only way there wouldn't be one is if there was an error inside the *get_latest_id* function. You could either have the checks inside the *get_latest_id* function or before the *get_report_obj* function.

Comment: no sometimes get_latest_id also return none its based on the status in my modal

Comment: can use like below.                                                                                                   
`def get_report_obj(id=get_latest_id()):                                                                          
       if not id:
             return False`